# Where is the iPhone simulator .app file with Xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode4.5

I installed Xcode 4.5 and the installation caused the iPhone simulator alias to disappear from the dock. So I want to put it back on the dock but I can't find the .app file (or whatever the file might be called).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xcode 4.5 the simulator is included in the Xcode package. Find it by right clicking Xcode.app in the Applications folder and choosing "Show Package Contents" then navigate to:

Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iOS Simulator.app

If you use it a lot drag it to the dock.